# How to hold back a named branch while pushing the default branch?

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs, push

Say I commit some changes to a new local named branch called 'X'.  Then I commit some other changes to my 'default' branch.  Can I push *only* the changesets on 'default', but *not* the changes on 'X'?

Might my approach be wrong? If so, please offer criticism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much.  Just do this:

```
hg push -r default
```

When you use the `-r X` option with `push`, `pull`, or `clone`.  You're saying "Get me the newest changeset that matches X **and all of its ancestors**.  So if you do `hg push -r default` you send the newest changeset on `default` and all of its ancestors.  So changesets on other branches that were merged into default will go to, but if you've kept the branches separate you'll be sending only default.

Note that you can always test your push with `hg outgoing -r default` to see exactly what you'd push.

Here's a nice write up with a way to make pushing only the branch on which you're working a one command affair: http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-09-28-nudge-a-gentler-push/